# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, excel, csv

i just copied an excel file into .csv file.

after copying i want to delete .csv file by unset method.
but file is not getting deleted and i'm getting an error  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING**

my code is:

```
<?php

copy('Book1.xlsx','test.csv');
unset('test.xlsx');

?>
```

Comment: its `unlink`, not `unset`

Comment: And the parser error is basically saying: "I was expecting a variable, but you sent me a string"

Comment: There's also a [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename) function.

Comment: @mario make an answer with the `rename` function. I think is explicitly better than doing two function calls.

Answer (score 4):

[`unset()`](https://www.php.net/unset) is used to delete *variables*. You need to use [`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/unlink) to delete *files*.